# How to check if the current user is authenticated on Firebase (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm just trying out Firebase for the first time.

In my Firebase Realtime Database, I maintain a list of banned users' UIDs in a child named `blockedUsers`. My security rules is as followed

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "!root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    ".write": "!root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
  }
}
```

So far it works, if a user that is in `blockedUsers` open the app, they can't read anything. But I want to stop them at MainActivity; that is, if the banned user opens the app, they will be instantly redirected to a screen saying they're banned. Thing is, I can't retrieve `blockedUsers`, because well, I'm blocked. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: So just to clarify what exactly is happening here, maybe this would help any future reader
- I store a list of banned users' UID in node called `blockedUsers`. Supposedly if a user is in this list, they can't do anything on the app at all. What happened was that they could still open the MainActivity, just that nothing loads for them. 

However what I want is for the banned user to immediately be redirected to a blank page saying they're banned at the very beginning. But to do that, I have to check their banned status. And I can't check, because I'm banned and can't read the list.

Answer (score 0):

Security rules don't affect the way your application code works.  It just affects the results of queries that you code makes when querying Realtime Database.

If you want your app to behave differently based on security rules, you will have to write a query that is expected to be allowed or denied by the rules, then decide what to do with that result.

Comment: Actually, I worked my way around it. When listening for the database node as I retrieve the banned user list, if the user is banned, it will throw a DatabaseError in onCancelled(). I took that as the cue that this user is banned and set a flag.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using email as registration the best way can be using UID's.
Maintain two child nodes in database and just compare with it and rest all of your code.